# How to construct Følner sequences?

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups, amenability

**Q1.** Are there "canonical" ways to construct [Følner sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B8lner_sequence)  for locally compact amenable groups? Possibly via representations or perhaps characters ?

To elaborate, let $G$ be a l.c. amenable group with the left Haar measure $\lambda$. We say the sequence $F_n$ of compact non-zero measure subsets with $G=\cup A_n$ is a Følner sequence if for any compact set $K$ and $\delta>0$ 
$$\lambda(KF_n\Delta F_n)\leq \delta \lambda(F_n),$$ for large enough $n$. People sometimes assume extra restrictions such as symmetry of$F_n$ and that each $F_n$ contains of the identity. But let us not worry for about that for now.

**Q2.** Are there ergodic theorems similar to Lindensrauss' for amenable groups with conditions on Følner sequences rather than Shulman's (that is
$\lambda(\cup_{k<n} F^{-1}_kF_n)\leq C\lambda(F_n)$ for all $n$?)

Comment: Remark: if $G$ is not $\sigma$-compact then there is no such sequence: indeed, let $U$ be an open $\sigma$-compact subgroup containing $\bigcup F_n$. Then for all $g\notin U$, $gF_n\cap F_n$ is empty. In this generality, we need a net of Følner subsets rather than a sequence.

Comment: Second remark: the assumption that $F_n$ is mild since it can be achieved up to replace $F_n$ with a right translate.

Comment: Third remark: the assumption that $F_n$ is symmetric is not usual at all. Actually, there is a net of symmetric Følner subsets in $G$ if and only $G$ is **amenable and unimodular**.

Comment: Very interesting. I was not aware of the statement in your third remark and actually showed a little proposition stating that a certain amenable L.C group (non-unimodular) has no compact symmetric subset! Now Im trying to cook up a net(or sequence) satisfying Folner condition, a task that Greenleaf-Emerson couldn't accomplish.

Comment: not sure what you mean: every locally compact group has compact symmetric subsets of nonempty interior (pick any compact neighborhood $V$ of unit and consider $V\cap V^{-1}$).

Comment: Yeah of course. But it may not necessarily generate the group as in the statement you mentioned. What I meant to say was that a particular L.C group doest not contain a compact symmetric set $F$ such that $\cup F^n=$group.

Comment: Yes, this is called "compactly generated". In restriction to discrete groups it's called "finitely generated". It's quite a trivial exercise to construct countable groups that are not finitely generated (amenable if you like, e.g. abelian). An example is a locally finite countable group, that is a group $G$ that is an increasing union of finite subgroups $F_n$. In this case $(F_n)$ is Følner.